# How to sketch slope field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'(x) = (y(x)(1+y(x)))/(1+x)$$

I need to sketch the slope field for this ODE (without using any software) and find the equilibrium solutions.

Any help on how to do that is much appreciated.

Comment: Given your screen name, it might be worth pointing out that Matplotlib's `quiver` function does what you want. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832763/drawing-directions-fields/18833385#18833385) is a nice example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is 'drawing arrows in the x-y-plane. Now for every point $(x,y)$ you can find $y'$ (the slope at that point) by putting $x$ and $y$ in your differential equation. Then you just have to draw an arrow with slope $y'$ at the point $(x,y)$.

Lets say you want to draw an arrow at $(x,y) = (1,2)$. You know from your equation that

$$y' = \frac{y(1+y)}{1+x} = 2(1+2)/(1+1) = 3.$$

So the slope at $(1,2)$ is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sketch a slope field, you just, at each grid point, draw a short section of line with the desired slope at that point. This required evaluating the slope at that point, but that is simple since you are actually *given* the slope:

$$y' = y  \frac{1 + y}{1 + x}$$

The extra $x$'s in the equation (as in $y(x)$) are not actually relevant, and just add clutter.

Answer (score 0):

To find equilibrium solution, we know that at the equilibrium the rate of change or our `y' or dy/dx` is zero. So, to find equilibrium points equate
 `y'(x) = y(x) * (1 + y(x))/ (1 + x) = 0` and solve for `y`. You have 
`y'(x) = 0 implies that y(x) = -1`  This is your equilibrium point. To make sure equilibrium point is stable you need slope field or directional field (both are same). Now you can take derivative of initial `y'(x)` to find where it achieves maximum or minimum. By doing this you know where the initial `y'(x)` increases and where decreases.